# How to arrange 16 people on 3 tables of at least one person without taking into account the order in which they are sited

Tags: combinatorics

I found this question very interesting.

On this article of [arranging 6 people on 3 indistinguishable tables](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3978458/1043928), the number of people is far smaller from that of my problem so I don't think the same method is applicable here.

I attempted by numerating the ways of grouping 16 people as follows:
Table 1: 14, Table 2: 1, Table 3: 1. Reducing the number of people on table 1 and increasing the number of people on table 2, keeping the number of people on table 3 constant, I obtained 13 ways. Now Reducing the number of people on table 1 and increasing the number of people on table 3, keeping the number of people on table 2 constant, and obtained 13 ways too, making in total 26 arrangements. Note that to increase the number of people on either table 2 or table 3, the number of people on table 1 can not be kept constant. I doubt if the solution is correct, where is the mistake ?

Comment: Are people $1$ through $10$ at table-1, and people $11$ through $16$ at table-2, with no one at table-3, considered a valid seating?  Further, is this seating considered to be distinct from the seating of people $1$ through $10$ at table-2 and people $11$ through $16$ at table-1?  Please edit your posting to identify the exact source of this problem, as well as the exact original wording of the problem.

Comment: Sometimes, I disagree with the general protocol at MathSE for posted problems, as detailed in [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).  In this particular case, I agree with the protocol and ask that you edit your posting accordingly.

Comment: Thank you @user2661923. Actually they are banquet tables (so distinct).
Futhermore, it's a hunch of mine that the minimum per table is 1 but the question is clearly stated as above

Comment: Please edit your question in accordance with the article that I cited.  Further, please explain your thinking, in very clear detail, re the equation $(13 \times 2) = 26.$  I am unable to perceive the logic behind that equation.

Comment: What do you mean by "Actually they are banquet tables (so distinct)" Why should banquet tables be necessarily distinct ? And you have a **hunch** that each table must have at least $1$, whereas your header clearly specifies tables of at least one. Unless there is clarity on these points, it is futile to respond.

Comment: In the problem that you linked to, in your posting: [1] the tables are circular.  [2] The people are (apparently) distinguishable. [3] The tables are (apparently) indistinguishable, based on the following excerpt from the answer given to the linked problem: "The table with four people in the first term is distinct from the tables with one; the two classes of tables cannot be swapped, but the two tables with one person can be."

Comment: Further, per the linked problem, "This problem was an introductory problem to Stirling numbers."  This makes me wonder what the source of the present problem is, involving $16$ people.  Stirling numbers get ugly, fast, and you normally wouldn't compose a problem involving $16$ people to reinforce concepts around Stirling numbers.  **I therefore ask again**: what is the source of the present problem that involves $16$ people, rather than $6$ people?

Comment: @trueblueanil See my preceding comments.  Taking the  problem that the OP linked to in his posting at face value, it would seem that the ambiguities have been resolved.  However, one wonders why someone would compose a problem around Stirling numbers that involves as many as $16$ people.  As I suggested, it seems to me that Stirling numbers get ugly fast.

Comment: Thank you all, the world need more people like you.
Unfortunately I got no further information about the Question's origin I found it in a block of class exercises and my comprehension is still limited but I'm trying to solve it, Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Put a number $0,1,2$ on each table. Now they are distinguishable. Assign a position to each person. You can list the tables each person is at in sequence: "$0122011020102211$". Interpret this as a 16-digit base-3 number. How many such numbers are there? A valid assignment is one which has all three digits present, so throw out the numbers that are missing a digit. (hint: how many numbers are there with just $0,1$ as digits?, how many with just $0$ as digits?). Divide by the number of permutations of $0,1,2$ to get the undistinguished tables answer.